# Authentication custom redirect callback

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, provider

I have integrated Firebase/authentication with my React web app using the Javascript SDK. I setup Github sign-in using the redirect method. After a user successfully authenticates with Github, they are redirected back to my login form. I have set the listener `onAuthStateChanged` to my `componentWillMount` to push a route once a user is recognized.

I would like to show a loading icon while the `onAuthStateChanged` is checking the state of the user. But, I have no way of knowing that the page was called from the Firebase redirect, unless the callback includes something in the url, ie. `website.com/login-form/from-firebase-callback/`

any ideas on how to set this up? I have looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything. I'm hoping this is a quick config fix somewhere, as I don't want to set up the flow manually.

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {

        // would like to add a something to the url from the firebase redirect
        const query = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
        if (query === 'from-firebase-callback') {
            this.isLoading = true;
        }

        const authChangedListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.loading = false;
                this.props.history.push('/dashboard/');
            } else {
                console.log('no user...');
            }
        });
    }

... rest of component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting stuck on the inability to pass state from different URLs, you could use a combination of the onAuthStateChanged listener to determine if the user is logged in or not by checking for state.user, and state.loading to keep track of the loading state.

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
         super();

         this.state={
             loading:true
         }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({loading:false,user})
                this.props.history.push('/dashboard/');
            } else {
                this.setState({loading:false})
            }
        });
    }
    ... rest of component
}
```

Comment: thanks this works, i was overthinking it and didnt fully understand how `onAuthStateChanged` works, but the else clause does return the correct state